# R Sorting data into a data frame

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

Let's say I've got the following data:

```
structure(c(4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Names = c("oranges_53", 
"oranges_32", "squash_53", "bananas_542", "bananas_32", "oranges_542", 
"squash_32", "bananas_12", "oranges_12", "squash_12", "bananas_53", 
"squash_542"))
```

The data is an integer vector, with names. The header names 
of this data are all in the format `fruit_integer` where `fruit` is
one of `c("oranges", "bananas", "squash")`, and `integer` is one of `c(32, 542, 12, 53)`. Let's say that the lists I just gave are also the order I want my data presented in (fruit going down the rows, integers going across the columns).

I would like to turn the data into a data frame that looks like this:

```
          | 32 | 542 | 12 | 53 |
| oranges |  4 |   5 |  5 |  4 |
| bananas |  5 |   4 |  5 |  5 |
| squash  |  3 |   3 |  3 |  2 |
```

What is the best way to create this data frame from this integer vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new data.frame from your original data and make a `separate`, `spread` operation after that:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr);
df <- data.frame(names = names(data), value = as.numeric(data))
separate(df, names, into=c("fruit", "number"), sep = "_") %>% spread(number, value)
    fruit 12 32 53 542
1 bananas  5  5  3   4
2 oranges  5  4  4   5
3  squash  3  3  2   3
```

**Data**:

```
data <- structure(c(4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Names = c("oranges_53", 
"oranges_32", "squash_53", "bananas_542", "bananas_32", "oranges_542", 
"squash_32", "bananas_12", "oranges_12", "squash_12", "bananas_53", 
"squash_542"))
```

Comment: To create `df`, you might alternately use `stack(data)`

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this in base R. Assuming that we store your structure in `exdata`...

```
# Set stringsAsFactors off
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Create a data frame containing the information in your vector
exdata_df <- data.frame(vecname = names(exdata),
                        value = exdata)

# Next, split the names into two parts, the fruit and the integer
# Extract each using sapply() and put them in columns in our exdata_df frame
split_names <- strsplit(x = exdata_df$vecname,split = "_")
exdata_df$fruit <- sapply(X = split_names,FUN = `[[`,1)
exdata_df$integer <- sapply(X = split_names,FUN = `[[`,2)

# Now, use the vanilla reshape() command to reshape the data
exdata_reshaped <- reshape(data = exdata_df[c("value","fruit","integer")],
                           v.names = "value",
                           timevar = "integer",
                           idvar = "fruit",
                           direction = "wide")

# The only downside is tht the names will be value.NN, not just NN
# R doesn't like pure integer names for columns - but you can override this
# later if you would like. Similarly, you can drop the rownames.

> exdata_reshaped
              fruit value.53 value.32 value.542 value.12
oranges_53  oranges        4        4         5        5
squash_53    squash        2        3         3        3
bananas_542 bananas        3        5         4        5
```

Comment: Looks good to me. You can save a tiny bit of typing by assigning a time variable `reshape` will recognise automatically, like: `spln <- strsplit(names(dat), "_"); tmp <- data.frame(fruit=sapply(spln, \`[\`, 1), time=sapply(spln, \`[\`, 2), value=dat); reshape(tmp, idvar="fruit", direction="wide")` but essentially my logic was identical.

Comment: Yeah, I thought more explicitness was good for the example. Also, the base `reshape()` is very non-intuitive (in fact, most people don't seem to know that there _is_ a `reshape` in base R.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `melt/dcast`

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
dcast(setDT(melt(as.list(df1)))[, c("V1", "V2"):=tstrsplit(L1, "_")],
                      V1~V2, value.var="value")
#        V1 12 32 53 542
#1: bananas  5  5  3   4
#2: oranges  5  4  4   5
#3:  squash  3  3  2   3
```